# How can I set up Gmail on my iPhone 4S with Exchange?

Tags: iphone, gmail, exchange-activesync

I have set up my Gmail account to send and receive messages from my business email address over Exchange on my iPhone 4S. I receive all messages fine, but it doesn't send messages from my business email address unless I am logged into Gmail in a web browser.

Comment: It sounds like an outgoing mail problem. You have to have a browser tab open with your Gmail account in order for it to send? It works then?

Answer (score 2):

http://support.google.com/mobile/bin/answer.py?hl=en&topic=14252&answer=138740

The only thing to notice is the m.google.com server address.

Comment: Links may break over time. Please summarize the content of your link. ;)

Comment: -1 for the comment. The content provided by Google is likely to change before the link does... :)

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to Settings -> Mail -> Default Account; check that this is set to "Exchange" and not something else.